# GeoJSON adm-2 USA data same name county/district filter based on state

Tags: geojson

On GeoJSON adm-2 I can see the USA Dallas have more than object and does not have associated state, on below pic you can see there is no column represent the adm-2 belongs to which state.

How we can filter based on state?

Download file from this URL: https://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/blob/main/sourceData/gbOpen/USA_ADM2.zip

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the GIS software in use, identify where you got the data, and indicate any processing or filtering steps you performed to get the data in its current displayed form. In my experience all admin level 2 data always indicates the level 1, if not level 1 *and* level 0, so context is necessary to understand your question.

Comment: Thanks Vince. I will share but if you already have the admin level's indicate details Plz share those files.

Comment: Update the downloaded source URL in the description.